# Integration Question

Tags: calculus, integration

If we know the integral $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+1}$$ can we find the integral of $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+c}$$ for arbitrary $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (where defined)? Does it make a difference if the integral is definite and $f$ is periodic (over any interval that may prove helpful)?

Clarification: Can the second integral be expressed in terms of the first?

Comment: Dont dont see : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%5E%28pi%29%2B1%29

Comment: @Awesome I'm a little confused... what's your point?

Comment: I misunderstood your question... my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider two integrals $$I_1=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+1}$$ $$I_2=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{g(y)+c}$$ If it is possible to make a change of variable such that $$g(y)+c=f(x)+1$$ that is to say $$y=g^{-1}(f(x)+1-c)$$ the denominators of the integrands will become the same. However, we shall have the problem of $\frac {dy}{dx}$; if this is a constant, say $\frac {dy}{dx}=k$, the answer is yes.

For example $f(x)=a x+b$ will lead to $$I_1=\frac{\log (a x+b+1)}{a}$$  $$I_2=\frac{\log (a x+b+c)}{a}$$ but $f(x)=\sin(x)$ will lead to $$I_1=\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$ $$I_2=\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c \tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}$$